# Proguard Warning error regarding libraries while generating signed apk

Tags: android-proguard

Can any one help me out with the issue proguard rules warnings

Note: the configuration refers to the unknown class 'com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.BasePendingResult.ReleasableResultGuardian'
Note: the configuration refers to the unknown class 'com.google.android.gms.common.internal.safeparcel.SafeParcelable'
Warning: com.amazonaws.util.json.JacksonFactory: can't find referenced class com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonFactory
Warning: com.amazonaws.util.json.JacksonFactory: can't find referenced class com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonFactory
Warning: com.amazonaws.util.json.JacksonFactory: can't find referenced class com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonToken
Warning: com.amazonaws.util.json.JacksonFactory: can't find referenced class com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonToken
Warning: com.amazonaws.util.json.JacksonFactory: can't find referenced class com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonFactory
Warning: com.amazonaws.util.json.JacksonFactory: can't find referenced class com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonToken
Warning: com.amazonaws.util.json.JacksonFactory: can't find referenced class com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonToken
Warning: com.amazonaws.util.json.JacksonFactory: can't find referenced class com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonToken
Warning: com.amazonaws.util.json.JacksonFactory: can't find referenced class com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonToken
Warning: com.amazonaws.util.json.JacksonFactory$1: can't find referenced class com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonToken
Warning: com.amazonaws.util.json.JacksonFactory$1: can't find referenced class com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonToken
Warning: com.amazonaws.util.json.JacksonFactory$1: can't find referenced class com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonToken
Warning: com.amazonaws.util.json.JacksonFactory$1: can't find referenced class com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonToken
Warning: com.amazonaws.util.json.JacksonFactory$1: can't find referenced class com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonToken
Warning: com.amazonaws.util.json.JacksonFactory$1: can't find referenced class com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonToken
Warning: com.amazonaws.util.json.JacksonFactory$1: can't find referenced class com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonToken
Warning: com.amazonaws.util.json.JacksonFactory$1: can't find referenced class com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonToken
Warning: com.amazonaws.util.json.JacksonFactory$1: can't find referenced class com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonToken
Warning: com.amazonaws.util.json.JacksonFactory$1: can't find referenced class com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonToken
Warning: com.amazonaws.util.json.JacksonFactory$1: can't find referenced class com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonToken
Warning: com.amazonaws.util.json.JacksonFactory$1: can't find referenced class com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonToken
Warning: com.amazonaws.util.json.JacksonFactory$1: can't find referenced class com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonToken
Warning: com.amazonaws.util.json.JacksonFactory$1: can't find referenced class com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonToken
Warning: com.amazonaws.util.json.JacksonFactory$JacksonReader: can't find referenced class com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonFactory
Warning: com.amazonaws.util.json.JacksonFactory$JacksonReader: can't find referenced class com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonToken
Warning: com.amazonaws.util.json.JacksonFactory$JacksonReader: can't find referenced class com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonToken
Warning: com.amazonaws.util.json.JacksonFactory$JacksonReader: can't find referenced class com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonToken
Warning: com.amazonaws.util.json.JacksonFactory$JacksonReader: can't find referenced class com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonToken
Warning: com.amazonaws.util.json.JacksonFactory$JacksonReader: can't find referenced class com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonToken
Warning: com.amazonaws.util.json.JacksonFactory$JacksonReader: can't find referenced class com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParser
Warning: com.amazonaws.util.json.JacksonFactory$JacksonReader: can't find referenced class com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonToken
Warning: com.amazonaws.util.json.JacksonFactory$JacksonReader: can't find referenced class com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParser
Warning: com.amazonaws.util.json.JacksonFactory$JacksonReader: can't find referenced class com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParser

Answer (score 0):

in my case adding below value in proguard-rules.pro file resolved my problem.

```
-dontnote com.google.common.**
-keep public class com.google.android.gms.* { public *; }
-dontwarn com.google.android.gms.**
-dontwarn java.lang.ClassValue
-dontwarn com.google.common.base.**
-keep class com.google.common.base.** {*;}
-dontwarn com.google.errorprone.annotations.**
-keep class com.google.errorprone.annotations.** {*;}
-dontwarn com.google.j2objc.annotations.**
-keep class com.google.j2objc.annotations.** { *; }
-dontwarn java.lang.ClassValue
-keep class java.lang.ClassValue { *; }
-dontwarn org.codehaus.mojo.animal_sniffer.IgnoreJRERequirement
-keep class org.codehaus.mojo.animal_sniffer.IgnoreJRERequirement { *; }
```

Comment: updated my answer with complete properties which i used, can you please re try with this one, i hope it will help you.